# GDK Bug Reports

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

What is proper place to report Google Glass GDK bugs/feature request?  Is it the same as [Mirror API](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that tracker is being used both for Mirror API and GDK bug reports/feature requests.